# How to group python dicts by key?

Tags: python, algorithm

We have a list of dictionaries:

```py
example = [
    {'a': 11, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 11, 'b': 22, 'c': 33},
    {'a': 11, 'b': 222, 'c': 333}
]
```

How to group the dictionaries by repeating key `a`?

```py
example = {
    11: [
        {'b': 2, 'c': 3},
        {'b': 22, 'c': 33},
        {'b': 222, 'c': 333}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why not by `'b'` the key is also present in all dicts ... as is `'c'`? Why did `11` change to `'11'`? What did you try? Where is your [mre]? Did you follow [ask]? What happens if `'a':11`  and `'b':2`  are in all dicts?

Comment: The answer to your post is:   Find out which key:value is identical in all dicts, convert the value to string, put it into a new dict as key and as value use your old list. Then modify the dicts in this old list by removing the found key from it.

Comment: I know the identical value of key:value by definition.
upd: More precisely, I know the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping can be done using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby).

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. The key is a function computing a key value for each element. If not specified or is None, key defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged. Generally, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function.

```py
from itertools import groupby

example = [
    {'a': 11, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
    {'a': 11, 'b': 22, 'c': 33},
    {'a': 11, 'b': 222, 'c': 333}
]

for k, g in groupby(example, key=lambda v: v.pop("a", None)):
    print(k, list(g))
```

Output:

```
11 [{'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'b': 22, 'c': 33}, {'b': 222, 'c': 333}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too hard in O(n);

```
res_dic = {}
for dic in example :
    val = str(dic.pop('a'))
    if res_dic.get(val): 
       res_dic[val].append(dic)
    else: 
       res_dic[val] = [dic,]
```

Comment: (the usual test is `in` (and in contrast to singleton tuples, lists don't need a trailing `,`).)

Comment: For the trailing `,`: **Explicit is better than implicit, PEP 20, Zen of Python**. You don't need to nit-pick every answers, I'm not asking you to check my syntax especially if it makes no difference.